# $F(a)$ is a field such that $F\subseteq F(a), a\in F(a)$ and any field containing $F$ and $a$ contains $F(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F(a)$ is a field such that $F\subseteq F(a), a\in F(a)$ and any field containing $F$ and $a$ contains $F(a)$. Additionally, $c\in F, K\subseteq K$ and $a\in K$. I missed that information when I read the problem.
Prove: 1. $F(a)=F(a+c)$ and $F(a)=F(ca)$ where $c\neq 0$

2. $F(a^2)\subseteq F(a)$ and $F(a+b)\subseteq F(a,b).$ {$F(a,b)$ is a field containing $F,a, \text{and} b$.

For 1: I know we can use vector operations but I'm not sure how $a+c=a$ without $c=0$ or some congruence to $0$.

For 2: Since $a\in F$ then $a^2$ has to be an element of $F$. Any field containing $F, a$ will then contain $a^2$ thus it must also contain $F(a^2)$. I am sort of stuck on the addition part but I am sure that with proving 1, it will follow.

Could I have some help solving these? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What is $c$? Is it given that $c\in F$?

Comment: @Servaes ah, yes $c\in F K\subseteq K$ and $a\in K$. I missed that information when I read the problem.

Comment: You don't have $a+c = a$ but $F(a) = F(a+c)$. Those are two quite different things.

Comment: @md2perpe I understand this. I was referring more to $c\neq 0$ then I didn't know how they could be the same

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

1. If $k$ is any field containing $F$ and $a$, and $c\in F$, then
   $a+c\in k$.
2. If $k$ is any field containing $F$, $a$ and $b$, then $a+b\in k$.

It is a matter of understanding the definition of $F(u)$, which is your first sentence, and applying this to the fields in question.

Comment: So if $a\in K$ then $F(a)\in F$ and $c\in F$ then $F(a+c)\in F$, but how does this make them equal?

Answer (score 0):

**If $F \subseteq G$ are fields and $a$ some element, then to show $F(a) \subseteq G$ it's enough to show that $a \in G$.**

Thus, to show that $F(a) = F(a+c)$ for $c \in F$ you should show that

1. $a \in F(a+c)$
2. $a+c \in F(a)$

Here, since $c \in F$ you also have $-c \in F \subseteq F(a+c)$. Of course also $a+c \in F(a+c)$. Therefore, $a = (a+c) + (-c) \in F(a+c).$ This proves 1. Now 2. should be trivial.

To show $F(a+b) \subseteq F(a,b)$ you just need to prove that $a+b \in F(a,b)$. That's also trivial.

Comment: Why is $a\in F(a+c)$? It makes sense overall but how can I conclude this?

Comment: You have: 1) $a+c \in F(a+c)$ by definition, 2) $-c \in F(a+c)$ since $c \in F \subseteq F(a+c)$, 3) $F(a+c)$ is a field. Number 3) makes $F(a+c)$ be closed under addition, so $a = (a+c) + (-c) \in F(a+c)$.

Comment: So $F(a+c+(-c))\rightarrow F(a)$ thus $F(a)=F(a+c)$?

Comment: I accidentally hit Enter too soon. I have now modified my comment. But I don't understand what you mean with $\to$.

Comment: I apologize it was just a placeholder for all the work I did not show. I have an additional question then. Can we assume that F has inverses?

Comment: Yes, one of the conditions on a field $F$ is that if $0 \neq x \in F$ then $1/x \in F$ (multiplicative inverses). Also $F$ is an additive group so $-x \in F$ (additive inverses).